# Angular 2 binding not working when run as chrome extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension using Angular.  I have a simple login form:

```
<div class="form-group">

<div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid Credentials</div>

<label>Username</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="username" class="form-control" />

<label>Password</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="password" class="form-control"  />

<button (click)="login(username, password)" class="btn btn-lg">Login</button>
</div>
```

and it works fine when i run the app in the browser - the login method on the controller is invoked with the correct values.

However, when I run the app in a chrome extension (loading my `dist` folder as an unpacked extension), the binding doesn't seem to work.  The `username` and `password` fields are undefined, but the login method is called.

I'm happy to provide as much info as possible, but is there something special I need to do to make the app bind correctly when run as a chrome extension?

Here's the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  username: string;
  password: string;
  error: boolean;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService,
    private storageService: StorageService,
    private router: Router) {

  }

login(username: string, password: string) {
this.loginService.login(username, password)
  .subscribe(result => {
    if (result) {
      this.error = false;
      this.router.navigateByUrl('customers');
    }
    else {
      this.error = true;
    }
  });
```

}
}

---

Here's the actual html while running the extension, i don't see the angular bindings applied:

```
<login><div class="form-group">

    <!---->

    <label>Username</label>
    <input class="form-control">

    <label>Password</label>
    <input class="form-control">

    <button class="btn btn-lg">Login</button>
</div></login>
```

Comment: please share corresponding angular code.

Comment: @yılmaz updated

Comment: I'd imagine this is zone.js related. Zone monkey-patches events (including keyup, keydown, etc) as a means of informing Angular about changes. Maybe it's having trouble doing so within this environment? You could try putting a `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in the first line of your login function, but I suspect you'll want to find a more universal solution.

Comment: @adamdport I was thinking it had to be something like that.  Though also that this must be a something others have come across and fixed.

Comment: @adamdport your comment led me to `NgZone.run` which is a working alternative.  Not ideal, but it keeps me moving.  Thanks.

Comment: I've definitely had Zone issues in my Cordova environment despite the Zone team claiming to have fixed it. It's still a young framework. Glad it helped!